# Reading an array from another Class

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a Class on a Theme.swift called Themes file which basically defines some types of Strings, and set different colours and font types.

On another file, called Contents.swift I have another class called Contents, and some arrays, like this:

```
class Contents: Themes {

   let navContent = [
        LabelContent(text: "NAV IDENT", theme: .menuOption),
        LabelContent(text: "WPT LIST", theme: .menuOption)
   ]  
}
```

The question is:
How can I use this navContent array in AppDelegate? It's not global yet I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create an instance of the class `Contents` and then get its properties, then make those properties static (or [Type Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)):

```
class Contents: Themes {
     static let navContent = [
             LabelContent(text: "NAV IDENT", theme: .menuOption),
             LabelContent(text: "WPT LIST", theme: .menuOption)
         ]  
}
```

And you could access them like so:

```
print(Contents.navContent[0])
```

Here is a brief description of **Type Properties** from the documentation:

> You can define properties that belong to the type itself, not to any one instance of that type. There will only ever be one copy of these properties, no matter how many instances of that type you create. These kinds of properties are called type properties.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I think it's not working properly. When I added the code lbLeft[1].text = Contents.navContent[0] I got the following error message: Cannot assign value of type 'Themes.LabelContent' to type 'String?' Basically, I added the class code you provided on Contents.Swift file, and the lbLeft[1].text = Contents.navContent[0] on viewController

Comment: `Contents.navContent[0]` is of type `LabelContent` and not String to affect it to `lbLeft[1].text`

Comment: @BrunoLelli to access the text property use `lbLeft[1].text = Contents.navContent[0].text`

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for more information

Comment: Have you made it ***static*** yet?

Answer (score 0):

if it's a member variable of the Contents class as you have it there, you need to create an instance of Contents, then access it from the instance

```
let instance = Contents()
instance.navContent // access it this way
```

if you dont want to create an instance everytime you need to access it, then you can make it into static class variable

```
class Contents: Themes {
    static let navContent = [
        LabelContent(text: "NAV IDENT", theme: .menuOption),
        LabelContent(text: "WPT LIST", theme: .menuOption)
    ]  
}
Contents.navContent // access it this way
```

if you need polymorphism on that variable, you can use the 'class' keyword on the variable and you can override it on the child class (but it needs to be a computed variable). you access it the same way as static class variable

```
class Contents: Themes {
    class var navContent: [LabelContent] {
        return [LabelContent(text: "NAV IDENT", theme: .menuOption)]
    }
}
class OtherContents: Contents {
    override class var navContent: [LabelContent] {
        return [LabelContent(text: "WPT LIST", theme: .menuOption)]
    }
}
Contents.navContent // access "NAV IDENT"
OtherContents.navContent // access "WPT LIST"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but I think it's not working properly.
When I added the code lbLeft[1].text = Contents.navContent[0] I got the following error message:
Cannot assign value of type 'Themes.LabelContent' to type 'String?'

Basically, I added the class code you provided on Contents.Swift file, and the lbLeft[1].text = Contents.navContent[0] on viewController

Comment: I think @Carpsen90 answered this above